# How to subscribe array of Observable Forkjoin not working

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am trying to do multiple HTTP requests in angular using forkjoin.But when I subscribe to Observable it doest not give any response.

```
 let data = this.email.map((email) =>
          this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email)
        );

        forkJoin([data]).subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });

        console.log('Execute');
```

Here is my service

```
  get_student_by_email_id(email) {
    return this.fire_store
      .collection('User', (ref) => ref.where('email', '==', email))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: can you get rid of the map and just do let data = this.get_student_sesrvices.get_student_by_email_id(this.email).  ?

Comment: Same problem unable to subscribe.Empty response

Comment: what is your `this.email`? when you get it? remember that you until you has no value in this.email you can not create the forkJoin and subscribe. It's looks like you give value to this.email in an async function and execute the forkJoin subscribe before the async function finished

Comment: this.email contains an array of email address's

Comment: `get_student_email() {
    this.get_project_service.get_project_by_doc_id(this.batchID, this.projectID)
  .subscribe((res) => { this.response = res;
    this.email = this.response.student;
    let data = this.response.student.map((email) =>
     this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email));
   let info = forkJoin([data]);console.log('info:', info);info.subscribe((res) => {console.log(res)console.log('Execute')})})}`

Comment: here is my code block

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you're getting unable to subscribe without the map function that helps, I think what is going on is that your get_student_xxx function is not returning an observable.

If that function returns an observable you will then be able to subscribe to it.

you could do this to get some extra help from the transpiler:

```
get_student_by_email_id(email) : Observable<someobject> {
...
}
```

So that gives you a couple of options... Maybe you need to just change the return value and not use Observable and subscribe?

Or maybe you need to return a different object that is an observable.

There are also ways to create your own observable, for example rxjs has a function called "of" that you can use to "wrap" an object in an observable:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { of } from 'rxjs';
//emits any number of provided values in sequence
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
//output: 1,2,3,4,5
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

also if your function returns an array of observables is it possible that [data] should just be data

Comment: No get_student function return array of obserable   ` [Observable, ObservablObservable, Observable]` like this and after forkjoin single Observable remain

Comment: if your function returns an array of observables is it possible that [data] should just be data ?

Comment: The problem remains the same how to subscribe to this Observable which is return by forkjoin call

Comment: i believe if forkJoin returns an observable than this is correct, and the issue is that forkjoin is currently not returning an observable. you could set the result of forkjoin to a variable and debug to ensure it is an observable?

Comment: forkjoin returns a single observable `let info = forkJoin(data); console.log('info:', info);`

Comment: **Output** info: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}

Comment: i understand that it is supposed to, but maybe there is an error.. maybe it's returning null.. also: ⚠ If an inner observable does not complete forkJoin will never emit a value.  so that is why i am recommending using the variable to make sure.  once again, i do not think it is returning a single observable, because if it did, subscribe would work

Comment: weird.. maybe try _subscribe?  not sure

Comment: yes this is a weird one.  i think i would try to do this get_student_by_email_id(email) : Observable.  and then the transpiler will ensure that an observable is being returned.  maybe even try to return of("test") in the function.  you could even try forkJoin(of("test")) and/or forkJoin([of("test")]) to make sure that is working

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I didn't get any answer.so now I reinitialized vanilla firebase in component.ts and try it works for me. if anyone solves this problem using angular fire please let me know.
here is my solution

```
const firebaseapp = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

get_student_email() {
    let store = firebaseapp.firestore();
    this.get_project_service
      .get_project_by_doc_id(this.batchID, this.projectID)
      .subscribe(async (res) => {
        this.response = res;
        this.email = [
          'admin@gmail.com',
          'test01@gmail.com',
          'intern01@gmail.com',
        ];
        const information = await Promise.all(
          this.email.map(async (i) => {
            let a = await store
              .collection('User')
              .where('email', '==', i)
              .get();
            let collection;
            a.forEach((element) => {
              collection = element.data();
            });
            return collection;
          })
        );
        //  request end
        console.log(information);
      });
    // subscriber End
  }
```